# using a render function inside a computed property with vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, functional-programming, vuetify.js

Ok so I am new to using render functions and this might be an odd question. Trying to dynamically load steps in a stepper function, right now my code looks like this:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
  {{steps}}
  </v-app>
</div>
...
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      e1: 0,
      mySteps: ['Boom', 'Wham', 'Kaboom!', 'superman']
    }
  },
  methods: {
    render(createElement){
      const stepperStep = createElement('v-stepper-step', 'Some step')
      const divideAndConquer = createElement('v-divider')
      return createElement('v-stepper', [
        stepperStep, divideAndConquer
      ])
    }
  },
  computed: {
    steps(){
      if (this.mySteps & this.mySteps.length > 0){
        return this.render(createElement)
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Why is nothing rendered (no errors as well) in my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The render function cannot be used with the `template` tag, the template tag will "override" the render function.

Furthermore, the render function cannot be inside the `method` keyword but directly in the first level of the script.

In your case your code should be:

```
<div id="app"></div>

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    // ...
    render(createElement){
      const stepperStep = createElement('v-stepper-step', 'Some step')
      const divideAndConquer = createElement('v-divider')
      return createElement('v-stepper', [
        stepperStep, divideAndConquer
      ])
    }
    // ...
  })
```

Inside your render function your must return some JSX that will be rendered inside your app

In the code above, the element `v-stepper` will be render and added to the `#app` element

cf: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html

Comment: Thanks, so just to clarify this works since there is `template` tag?
https://codepen.io/couellet/pen/YMbrvz
Furthermore, how is it that in this working example the render function is inside the `methods`?

Comment: The tag with the id `app` is necessary and needed by the Vue instance, but you cannot add something inside because the render function will render thing inside it. I edited my answer I missed that part :).

Comment: `Furthermore, how is it that in this working example the render function is inside the methods?` the `render` function isn't in the `methods` one, look carefully ;).

Comment: Now I am curious how I would go about selectively applying the render function, it is all in the same function `render` so not sure how that is accomplished?

Comment: I think you should read about the single file component, then you will be able to have a render function inside each components, and then separate your code to selectively apply things in the good component.